Flutter Most optimal way to implement a carousel of screens we can swipe with a fixed page indicator in the middle?
I am trying to create a carousel of screens in Flutter. The screens should be swiped left and right. I also need to have a page indicator (a row of circle outlined icons with the current page being a filled circle) in the middle of the screen. The indicator should remain fixed in the middle of the screen and not move when swiping the screens.
So far, I have split the screen into two parts and placed the indicator between them in the carousel, something like this:
Carousel(
  PageView( HeaderAndHeroOfScreen() ),
  PageIndicator(),
  PageView( BodyOfScreen() ),
);

Using two PageControllers, I have tried syncing the scrolling of the two PageViews:
void _syncPageViews() {
  _headerPageController.addListener(() {
    if (_headerPageController.position.isScrollingNotifier.value) {
      _bodyPageController.jumpTo(_headerPageController.offset);
    }
  });

  _bodyPageController.addListener(() {
    if (_bodyPageController.position.isScrollingNotifier.value) {
      _headerPageController.jumpTo(_bodyPageController.offset);
    }
  });
}

This approach works, but I had to turn off pageSnapping on the PageViews. With pageSnapping, if the scroll is slow, the page snaps back to the current position, without pageSnapping I seem to get laggy scrolling. Additionally, different pages have different background colors, which are preloaded for each page. The problem is that the page indicator's background doesn't change with swiping to the next page until we have landed on the next page.

Use a Stack, 1 PageView for both header and body, and place the Indicator accordingly on the screen, so it will be floating above the page which underneath swipes and changes

If you don't want to do it from scratch you can use appinio_swiper.
